# Select all records from one table where response is any and select record from other table where response is no

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle10g

I am using below query but this is not complete.

```
select whatsapp_user_contact.*, whatsapp_task.is_intimation_sent, whatsapp_task.is_ots_sent, whatsapp_task.is_ndc_sent, whatsapp_task.ndc_media_template_date,
whatsapp_task.ots_media_template_date,whatsapp_task.intimation_media_template_date
FROM whatsapp_user_contact
left join whatsapp_task on whatsapp_user_contact.loan_account_no = whatsapp_task.loan_account_no
where whatsapp_user_contact.sms_timestamp like
'05/06/19%'
order by whatsapp_user_contact.recordid asc;
```

I have two tables. I want to select all records from one table where response is yes, no or null but I don't want to select record from other table where response is no.

Comment: You've tagged 2 totally different database products... which one is it?

Comment: Also we need some sample data and expected results.

Comment: I would highly recommend learning about table aliases - they will make your query much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

```
select u.*, 
  t.is_intimation_sent, 
  t.is_ots_sent, 
  t.is_ndc_sent, 
  t.ndc_media_template_date,
  t.ots_media_template_date,
  t.intimation_media_template_date
FROM whatsapp_user_contact u 
     left join whatsapp_task t on u.loan_account_no = t.loan_account_no
where trunc(u.sms_timestamp) = date '2019-06-05'           --> dates aren't "like" anything
  and (u.response in ('yes', 'no') or u.response is null)  --> 1st table's responses
  and t.response <> 'no'                                   --> 2nd table's responses
order by u.recordid asc;
```

If `SMS_TIMESTAMP` column's datatype is `DATE`, then don't compare it to a string (because `'05/06/19%'` is a string, not a date), and don't use `like` against it. In this example, I *truncated* it which means that only *date* component will be used; *time* will be "removed", set to `00:00:00`.

Depending on the table description, this might not be the *best* option if there's an index on the `sms_timestamp` column. That can be fixed, no problem; I'm leaving it *as is* for simplicity.